# Android custom progress bar with .gif file

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

In my app i have a custom progress bar

progress.xml

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/loader" />
```

my gif file

[image: My gif image]

I want to create a progress bar with this image

In other word i want to show this image whenever i download data from server and remove it after downloading the data

or you can say , how to show this image as a progress bar

Comment: Were you able to find the solution?

Comment: Android does not support git images . You have to use different images in Drawable folder and animate them.

Follow this question :- [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900747/custom-progress-dialog-with-squre-image-rotation-with-asyntask)

Comment: If you need to use gif file again, I would recommend you to use [this](http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.in/2014/04/animated-gif-imageview-library-for.html) library instead of using several images. It's too simple and efficient. :)

Comment: I' ve never tried it but I think you can use WebView instead of using external library. Good luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- First Conver your Gif image to png Slice image sequence.
- Declare Your Progress bar as Image view.

  ```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/main_progress"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:visibility="visible" />
  ```
- Create .xml file in drawable folder using your .png sequence image those are generated from gif. In this case, Loading_web_animation.xml

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <animation-list    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:oneshot="false">
   <item
       android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_0"
       android:duration="40" />
   <item
       android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_1"
       android:duration="40" />
   <item
       android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_2"
       android:duration="40" />
   <item
       android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_3"
       android:duration="40" />
   <item
       android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_4"
       android:duration="40" />
   <item
       android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_5"
       android:duration="40" />
   <item
       android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_6"
       android:duration="40" />
   <item
       android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_7"
       android:duration="40" />
   <item
       android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_8"
       android:duration="40" />
   <item
       android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_9"
       android:duration="40" />
   <item
       android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_10"
       android:duration="40" />
   <item
       android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_11"
       android:duration="40" />
   </animation-list>
  ```
- In Main Activity set the code like,

  ```
   private AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;
   private ImageView mProgressBar;
   mProgressBar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loading_web_animation);
   animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable)mProgressBar.getBackground();
   mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   animationDrawable.start();
   mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   animationDrawable.stop();`
  ```

Comment: how this blocks the ui?

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm late to answer this, But you can try this also.

> XML

```
<FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/progress_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">
                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/circular_progress"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/circular_progress_counter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="10"/>
            </FrameLayout>
```

> my_progress_indeterminate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/process_icon"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

In Java File login to show Timer. here I used 10 second timer.

```
private void progressTimer() {
        handler = new Handler();

        if (maxCount >= 0) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    /*
                    Logic to set Time inside Progressbar
                     */

                    mCircularProgressCounter.setText(maxCount+"");

                    maxCount = maxCount - 1;
                    pickupTimer();

                }
            }, 1000);
        } 
    }

Result
```

[image]

Comment: It gives slow animation than expected. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Put your gif image in /res/raw folder

In your class declare mProgressDialog

```
TransparentProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
```

then use following code to show progress dialog

```
if (mProgressDialog == null)
    mProgressDialog = new TransparentProgressDialog(this);
if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    mProgressDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_progress_dialog));
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();
```

Create a class TransparentProgressDialog where .gif can be loaded using Glide library.

```
public class TransparentProgressDialog extends Dialog {

private ImageView iv;

public TransparentProgressDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.TransparentProgressDialog);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    wlmp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    getWindow().setAttributes(wlmp);
    setTitle(null);
    setCancelable(false);
    setOnCancelListener(null);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    iv = new ImageView(context);
    GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(iv);
    Glide.with(context).load(R.raw.gif_loader).into(imageViewTarget);

    layout.addView(iv, params);
    addContentView(layout, params);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I solved it before on this post easily:
[Custom progress bar with GIF (animated GIF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743947/custom-progress-bar-with-gif-animated-gif/48832734#48832734)

Use an ImageView that shows an Animated GIF and when need to show waiting make it visible and when works all will be done, make it Gone!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use an Animated icon.

1°) Create an XML  "animated" in Drawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/micro_1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/micro_2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/micro_3" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/micro_4" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/micro_3" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/micro_2" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

2°) Put an imageview in your layout

3°) Put the following code in your activity :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private int progressBarStatus = 0;
    private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();
    private ImageView micButton;
    //-- for testing progress bar
    private long fileSize = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //-- declare animation
        final AnimationDrawable[] rocketAnimation = new AnimationDrawable[1];
        final ImageView micButton = findViewById(R.id.mic_button);
        micButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.micro_1);
        //-- button listener
        micButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //-- init button with animation
                micButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mic_image);
                rocketAnimation[0] = (AnimationDrawable) micButton.getBackground();
                startprogress(rocketAnimation[0]);
            }
        });
    }


    public void startprogress(final AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation) {
         rocketAnimation.start();
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
         //--reset filesize for demo
        fileSize = 0;
        //-- thread for demo
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (progressBarStatus < 100) {
                    // process some tasks
                    progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();
                    // your computer is too fast, sleep 1 second
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // Update the progress bar
                    progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                        }
                    });
                }

                // ok, file is downloaded,
                if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {
                    // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // close the progress bar dialog
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                    if(rocketAnimation.isRunning()){
                        rocketAnimation.stop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

    // file download simulator... a really simple
    public int doSomeTasks() {

        while (fileSize <= 1000000) { //1000000

            fileSize++;

            if (fileSize == 100000) {
                return 10;
            } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
                return 20;
            } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
                return 30;
            } else if (fileSize == 400000) {
                return 40;
            } else if (fileSize == 500000) {
                return 50;
            } else if (fileSize == 600000) {
                return 60;
            }
        }

        return 100;
    }
}
```