# customized circular progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have been looking for a customised progress bar in android like one in the shell app. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: try adding gif image

Comment: You can implement this with some extra logic all you need to do is think!!! it's really simple to implement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688117/how-to-make-circle-custom-progress-bar-in-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Make Circle Custom Progress Bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688117/how-to-make-circle-custom-progress-bar-in-android)

Comment: @MartenCatcher no I've already checked that.

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi didn't get you?

Comment: @RichardDapice I have looked all of them. what I need should be exactly same as in the picture, thanks.

Comment: could you explain little more what you actually want to do with progress bar.?@HiraHashmi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302282/android-custom-progress-bar-with-gif-file have a look at ths question @HiraHashmi

Comment: Have you checked this https://github.com/glomadrian/dashed-circular-progress

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi you might have to look at all these resources and create one yourself, I doubt anything you find is going to be "exactly same as is in the picture" Good luck!