# Gradle dependencies to add gif library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am using the  these dependencies:

```
  compile 'com.felipecsl:gifimageview:2.1.0'
  compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
```

But it couldn't resolve the first one. I'm using Android Studio 2.3.2.

Comment: can you show your complete gradle file and also the error message in the gradle console ?

Comment: Sorry my reputations are less so can't upload images but the error message us coming as:-cannot resolve and with the dependencies mentioned  felipecsl

Comment: Copy past the text then :)

Answer (score 1):

try this library

```
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.0'
```

and this is the xml

```
 <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/gif1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Glide? It's like Picasso, a library to load an image into an ImageView, but it's "recommended by Google". Anyway, this library is similar to Picasso, but the difference is the ability to load a gif :)

Why not giving a try ? You can follow this stackoverflow example given by another member: [Displaying GIF in ImageView using Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36556415/displaying-gif-in-imageview-using-glide)