# Can I Add GIF format Image as a Splash Screen

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, gif, splash-screen

How can i add GIF format image as a splash screen. I tried to add but when i add it. It acts as a normal image. I don't know whether we can use  Gif image as splash Screen. if there is any option to work that GIF format image.

Comment: try this<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android>.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can Add Gif Image for the Splash Screen. To use Gif Image in your View.

add this dependency to your `build.gradle` file in the app module.

For the latest version.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.10'
}
```

and In the XML file add this way

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/yourgif_image"
    />
```

and add your Gif Image to Drawable.

For more detail visit this: https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

**Or**

you can Create different Frame for Image and add it one after another in short interval of time.

Comment: @chandra glad to know that.

Comment: For those wondering: you don't need to convert the gif file to another format. Just use the image file as is in your drawable or mipmap resources folder. Works great!

Comment: sorry but which XML file exactly?

Answer (score 4):

use glide to solve this.

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.splashScreen);
        GlideDrawableImageViewTarget splashScreen = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
        Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.gif_men_at_work).into(splashScreen);
```

go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082330/show-gif-file-with-glide-image-loading-and-caching-library?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) stackoverflow link for more detail