# React Native How To Set Gif Image at Splash Screen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have created new react native mobile application and I need to set gif image to the splash screen. any example or source code can help me to do that.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/*<BackgroundImage source={Images.splashScreen}*/}
        {/*       style = {{width: 315, height: 383}} />*/}

        <Image
            style={{width: 300, height: 200}}
            source={{uri: 'http://gifsstore.com/public/upload/gifs/15609427721560942769.gif'}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use [FastImage](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) for that functionality. It also gives support for gif files

**you can also try below code**

```
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image'

   <FastImage
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
            source={{
              uri: "your URL", //give your url here
              priority: FastImage.priority.normal
            }}
            resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
            onLoad={() => {
              setTimeout(
                () => {
                //navigate to another screen after some times
                },
                15000
              );
            }}
          />
```

Comment: @HusseinAbdAllahElGanzory Is it not loading black/white screen before animated gif ?

Answer (score 16):

These answers here seem a bit misleading. The question asks how to add this to a splash screen with react native. The solutions say how to add gifs to the project but not how to add them to a splashscreen.

*A splash screen is meant to be loaded before the JS bundle loads IE the `render` methods from react native will not be accessible before the JS bundle loads.*

### Solution: Android

Can actually have a gif directly in the splashscreen

Resources: [Can I Add GIF format Image as a Splash Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871405/can-i-add-gif-format-image-as-a-splash-screen)

Look at this repo as an example of integrating a gif into your splashscreen.
https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

I got it working tonight (4/12/2020) with *react native 0.62*

#### Steps:.

1. Follow the react-native-splash-screen tutorial to create `/layout/launch_screen/xml`
2. Add in the [android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) api
3. Bring a gif into the drawable folder and then link it like this:

`layout/launch_screen.xml` the `@drawable/tutorial` is my gif titled **tutorial.gif**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/splashscreen_bg"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:src="@drawable/tutorial"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

#### styles.xml

I was able to hide the white screen flash by using `<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>`

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
                <!-- Add the following line to set the default status bar color for all the app. -->

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/app_bg</item>
        <!-- Add the following line to set the default status bar text color for all the app 
        to be a light color (false) or a dark color (true) -->
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
        <!-- Add the following line to set the default background color for all the app. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/app_bg</item>
        <!-- Prevents white screen from appearing when opening the app -->
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

### Solution: iOS

1. Create a static splash screen with a static logo asset
2. After launch render an identical screen with the animated version of the logo

Hope this helps everyone!

Answer (score 1):

**GIF and WebP support on Android**

When building your own native code, GIF and WebP are not supported by default on Android.

You will need to add some optional modules in android/app/build.gradle, depending on the needs of your app.

```
dependencies {
  // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.10.0'

  // For animated GIF support
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.10.0'

  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.10.0'
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.10.0'

  // For WebP support, without animations
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.10.0'
}
```

Also, if you use GIF with ProGuard, you will need to add this rule in proguard-rules.pro :

```
-keep class com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.factory.AnimatedFactoryImpl {
  public AnimatedFactoryImpl(com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.PlatformBitmapFactory, com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ExecutorSupplier);
}
```

example

```js
<Image source={require('./path/to/image/loading.gif')} />
```

OR

```js
<Image source={{uri: 'http://www.urltogif/image.gif'}} />
```

[Apply Link to GIF](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#gif-and-webp-support-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.71/image#gif-and-webp-support-on-android

```
dependencies {
  // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'

  // For animated GIF support
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.5.0'

  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:2.5.0'
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.5.0'

  // For WebP support, without animations
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.5.0'
}
```