# How to add animated GIF as Splash Screen in iOS using react-native-splash-screen package

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

I was able to add animated splash screen in android using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/61182276/12132771 but for iOS I am not sure how to get same results.