# How to load GIF in ImageView background in android

Tags: android

This is my code where I am loading a gif from URL. I am using Glide Library. This code is not working, blank activity display

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_background_gif);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);

            //Glide.with(this).load(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample_img)).into(imageView);

            Glide.with(this)
                    .load("http://more-sky.com/data/out/6/IMG_105566.gif")
                    .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView));

        }
```

Comment: do you have Internet permission?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this

```
 Glide.with(context)
.load(imageUrl)
.asGif()
.placeholder(R.drawable.loading2)
.crossFade()
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082330/show-gif-file-with-glide-image-loading-and-caching-library

Answer (score 1):

you can programatically achieve it,
follow this link

http://www.geeks.gallery/how-to-display-the-animated-gif-image-in-android/

OR use library,

https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Picasso

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView to load GIF image. Implementation is very easy and works like a charm. Create html page. Here's the code:

```
<html style="margin: 0;">
<body style="margin: 0;">
<img src="imagename.gif" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />
</body>
</html>
```

Create assets folder and create html folder in assets. Copy Gif image and webpage in html folder. Add WebView in your xml.

MainActivity

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //for gif without background
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/HTML_PAGE_NAME.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

From P OS gif is now directly supported by Android and it is easy to load.
Java Code (loading from file):

```
ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(new File(fileName));
AnimatedImageDrawable drawable = (AnimatedImageDrawable) ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(source);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
drawable.start();
```

Kotlin code(loading from assets):

```
val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(assets, assetFileName)
val drawable = ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(source)

imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable)
if (drawable is AnimatedImageDrawable) {
  drawable.start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Movie class to display animated GIF according to [this page](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-play-gif-file-use-android-graphics-movie-class/). Below is the class I created to diaplay the gif and method invoking it.
It is deprecated from SDK 28 and AnimatedImageView is recommended. I used both and it turned out to me that old, unofficial way (with Movie) is faster and more reliable (AnimatedImageView hangs freezes sometimes).

Class to display animiated GIF with Movie

```
public class ShowGifView extends View {
    private Movie movie;
    private int gifImageDrawableId;
    private final Context ctx;
    private long gifStart = 0;

    public ShowGifView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // Make the custom view focus.
        setFocusable(true);
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (gifStart == 0) {
            gifStart = now;
        }

        if (movie != null) {
            // Get gif movie duration time.
            int duration = movie.duration();
            if (duration == 0) {
                duration = 1000;
            }

            // Get played frame percentage.
            int relTime = (int)((now - gifStart) % duration);

            // Set current gif frame time.
            movie.setTime(relTime);

            // Get custom view width and height.
            int width = this.getWidth();
            int height = this.getHeight();

            // Get gif image width and height.
            int movieWidth = movie.width();
            int movieHeight = movie.height();

            // Scale canvas size to fit the custom view.
            canvas.scale((float)width / movieWidth, (float)height / movieHeight);

            // Draw the gif image frame to custom view canvas.
            movie.draw(canvas, 1, 1);

            // This method will invoke onDraw method.
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if(movie != null){
            int scale = heightMeasureSpec / movie.height();
            setMeasuredDimension(movie.width() * scale, movie.height() * scale);
        }else{
            setMeasuredDimension(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
        }
    }

    public int getGifImageDrawableId() {
        return gifImageDrawableId;
    }

    public void setGifImageDrawableId(int gifImageDrawableId) {
        this.gifImageDrawableId = gifImageDrawableId;
    }

    // Call this method to read the drawable gif image to create movie object.
    public void drawGif()  {
        Resources resources = ctx.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(gifImageDrawableId);
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(inputStream);

        // Invalidate the view and invoke onDraw method.
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Method invoking this:

```
    private View addAnimatedGif(ConstraintLayout lout, int animatedGif) {
        ShowGifView resultView = new ShowGifView(getApplicationContext());

        // Set Layer type to display animated GIF on all APIs
        resultView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, new Paint());
        resultView.setGifImageDrawableId(animatedGif);
        resultView.drawGif();

        ConstraintSet cSet = new ConstraintSet();
        lout.addView(resultView);
        resultView.setId(View.generateViewId());
        int id = resultView.getId();

        cSet.clone(lout);
        cSet.connect(id, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 0);
        cSet.connect(id, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
        cSet.connect(id, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, 0);
        cSet.connect(id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);

        cSet.applyTo(lout);

        return resultView;
    }
```