# Parsing Gif image is reducing the quality and stacking frames

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I have a gif image as

[image]

However using glide i do this

```
  Glide.with(this)
                    .load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/" + "stickers/" + emoji))
                    .into(gifImage);
```

What i get is

[image]

Exactly what is going on, I have tried GifImageView library too and result is same. How can i parse gif image properly in android?

after adding datasource

[image]

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/chateeGifImage"
                />
```

Comment: already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082330/show-gif-file-with-glide-image-loading-and-caching-library

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya asGif is not the problem, its still the same, it is animating, but u can see one frame is stacked

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
Glide.with(con).load(url).asGif().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(ivImage);
```

Comment: it has improved the blur but one frame is still set like sample image

Comment: pls add your xml for the image your are loading gif image.

Comment: its simple ImageView , i just placed it

Comment: I think you have to enable GPU emulation in your emulator. I tried the same its working perfectly in real device (tried both 100x100dp and match_parent) make sure your gpu configuration are ok and try

Comment: already tried on device, its the same. :( I am not sure what could be the problem, tried on s4 samsung