# Android Custom Dailog

Tags: android

I am using a Custom Dialog in my application.So for I have created a Custom Dialog class in which i have called an XML layout which contains a imageview.

**Here is my CustomDialog class code...**

[image]

```
    public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

        public static CustomDialog newInstance() {
            return new CustomDialog();
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false);
            Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.loader1).placeholder(R.drawable.loader1)
                                   .into((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.progress));  //loader1 is a gif file
            getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

            if (getDialog() == null)
            super.setShowsDialog (false);
            return v;
            }

            }
```

**And here is my xml file code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView                           //image view containing the loader gif
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I put my gif in all the drawable folders but still the gif loader gets blurred while rotating in any of the device size whether hdpi,mpdi,etc..
Suggest me the solution so that the loader does not gets blurred

Comment: you cannot load gif image with glide instance

Comment: what is the exact problem:    displaying custom dialog box or displaying loader ?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34870817/2750390

Comment: @ApoorvMehrotra displaying loader is the problem

Comment: You can use `WebView` also in dialog. and load image like `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/piggy.gif"); `

Comment: @MayurRaval this works but this shows the gif with white background .I want it to be transparent

Comment: This  imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); does not set The background color of the loader as transparet @Mayur Raval

Comment: If you want to set background color for imageview then use `imageView.setBackgroundColor` instead of  `imageView.setBackgroundDrawable`

Comment: Not working @Piyush

Comment: Are you setting background color as a  _imageView.setBackgroundColor(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));_ ? @neha

Comment: hmm yaa @Piyush

Comment: Use  `imageView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this ,android.R.color.transparent));` @neha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133258/discussion-between-piyush-and-neha).

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Glide code to this to test

```
Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.loading).asGif().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).crossFade().into(loadingImageView);
```

or using this library https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable to load gifs

**EDIT:** If you use above library, change `android:background="@drawable/bg_anim` from xml to `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

**EDIT2**: According to Glide owner, version 3.8.0-SNAPSHOT or later will solve the transparent function. Use this:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Comment: this also shows the gif with white background .I want it to be transparent

Comment: I used this line of code Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.loading).asGif().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).crossFade().into(loadingImageView);

Comment: @neha manual `loadingImageView` xml set background to transparent like above

Comment: This also doesnt work,,check my edited question..See the screenshot