# not able to display animated gif in imageview in android using glide

Tags: android, url, android-glide

My code is like this:

```
String gifUrl = "http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--B7tUiM5l--/gf2r69yorbdesguga10i.gif";


Glide
   .with( mContext )
   .load( gifUrl )
   .error( R.drawable.sample )
   .into( imageViewTarget );
```

imageViewTarget is a normal imageview. But it is not loading the gif in the imageview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show GIF file with Glide (image loading and caching library)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082330/show-gif-file-with-glide-image-loading-and-caching-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but may take time in loading gif.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewPreview = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load("http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--B7tUiM5l--/gf2r69yorbdesguga10i.gif")
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Log.e("MyApp", "onException: "+model+" Exception: "+e );
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Log.e("MyApp", "onResourceReady: "+model );
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(imageViewPreview);
```

Comment: is It the Download time or the loading time? gif is only 354kb , still taking time. Any work around for that?

Comment: It loads just fine from local but takes time from url.
Try to add this: .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)

For more details check this issue: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/600

Answer (score 0):

use GlideDrawableImageViewTarget

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
Glide.with(this).load(gifUrl).into(imageViewTarget);
```

or

```
 Glide.with(context)
.load(gifUrl)
.asGif()
.placeholder(R.drawable.sample)
.crossFade()
.into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use transition or animation for Glide.It will solve your problem

Code :

```
Glide.with(context) .load(imgurl) 
.apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE) 
.error(R.drawable.no_image)) .into(holder.imageView);
```