# How to show an animated GIF in splash screen?

Tags: android, splash-screen, photoshop

I have an animated GIF I created and I want to put it on the splash screen.
There are way to show bitmap

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">

<item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

<item>

    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/fiadr"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</item>


</layer-list>
```

But I found no way to use animated GIFs.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options,

1) Use Glide to display that GIF 
`Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.image_gif).asGif().into(imageView);`

https://bumptech.github.io/glide/

[Show GIF file with Glide (image loading and caching library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082330/show-gif-file-with-glide-image-loading-and-caching-library)

2) Convert your animation to be in Adobe After Affects and use [Lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/) to show it. [Instructions](http://airbnb.io/lottie/android/android.html#sample-app)

I recommend option #2 if you are able to convert your animation to After Affects. Lottie will be soother and look better for your users than a GIF.

Comment: Oh...I used photoshop tho...I don't think there's a way to switch between the two. Is there?

Comment: That doesn't really work...The app takes time to load...which means it's would be like playing a gif after blank splash screen