# Long press function in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener

I am trying to convert a gif when I realised that it should be normal. Code in Kotlin below. I have tried using long press but when I am releasing, its not returning to image.

```
var walk1: ImageView?=null
var walk2: ImageView?=null
 walk1=findViewById(R.id.walky)
        walk2=findViewById(R.id.walky1)

        walk1?.setOnLongClickListener { walk2?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
           walk2?.setOnClickListener(){ walk2?.visibility=View.GONE
              return@setOnTouchListener true`enter code here`
           }
            return@setOnLongClickListener true

        }
```

Comment: Please format your code and explain your problem (both question title and content) more detail then we can help you. Currently I think most of people don't know what is your problem and what do you want to have

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Your question is asking two thing. 
One is about `OnLongClickListener` and I answered below by original answer.

And the other is about displaying gif, and you need to use image library, named `Glide`.

Read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493206/850347

First, add this code to your `app/build.gradle`

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

And then, sync your gradle. After you edit `build.gradle` file, you can see notice bar (top of the screen).

Next, add this code to your kotlin file. Change `R.raw.image_gif` to your gif file name.

```
Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.raw.image_gif).into(walk1);
```

**Original:**

You are setting `LongClickListener` on `walk1`, and `ClickListener` on `walk2`.

In this case, you need to focus on the return value of the `LongClickListener`.

Almost every method associated with event, `return true` means "I want to consume event and don't want it propagated. This point is end of the event." `return false` means "I just want to process my event, and the event will propagate to it's parent view (or child view)"

Last line of kotlin method (which needs return) means "return". So in this code, `false` is equivalent to `return false`.

```
val walk1: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.walky)
val walk2: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.walky1)

walk1.setOnLongClickListener {
    walk2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    false // Don't consume event, if return false. Consume event if true.
}

walk2.setOnClickListener {
    walk2.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Comment: its not working!!.  when i click long press its showing second walk2 but when i realised button its not showing walk1.

Comment: What is your goal? Show both ImageView at once?

Comment: Then, add your code that show your view above “false” line.

Comment: when i click on that button i should display gif and when realise button it should show normal pic in this above code walk1 is normal and walk2 is gif code

Comment: @rohit palankar Oh, you need to use glide library. ImageView doesn’t support gif. Read this: https://github.com/bumptech/glide And this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493206/850347