# How to use Glide to play gif

Tags: android, gif, android-glide

I use glide to load the same gif in my app project and a demo project, it works in the demo but doesn't work in my app project. Did anyone meet the same problem?

glide version:4.9.0

```java
 Glide.with(this).asGif().load(gifUrl).into(imageView);
```

Comment: have you cross checked that you are providing a gif url to Glide

Comment: Are you using Kotlin or Java on both projects?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082330/show-gif-file-with-glide-image-loading-and-caching-library

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" what do u mean? Is there an error? does it load to gif but as an image? does it load a black image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Glide.with(yourContext).asGif().load(R.raw.image_gif).into(yourImageView);
```

Comment: He already tried with something like this. If you check his code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Provide internet permission in AndroidMenifest.xml file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And glide module

```
 Glide.with(context)
        .load(gifUrl)
        .into(yourImageView)
```