# How to make loading screen in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-animation, loading, progressdialog

I am a newbie in android. I want to make an application that show dialog loading when I get data from server. I want my loading screen such as this picture below: 
[image: Loading Screen]

I don't know any key to searching to make this loading :(. Is This application show in the picture using progress bar with animation?. I have some picture when I extract apk file of this application and I have some pictures as below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that you can found some template in this site http://www.material.uplabs.com/

Comment: @YagamiLight thanks you bro. But I don't see anything like this :(. Moreover I don't want to use other library, I want to custom it :(

Comment: the problem is that in my office i can't see images (proxy .. ) but to understand your problem you want to do a simple loading circle or an activity

Comment: @YagamiLight no bro. I can make simple loading circle. I don't know how I can explain for u understand. U will understand what I need when u see my pictures upload above :(

Answer (score 0):

try this.

in run() put code which rewrite your progressbar...

if you want stop timer. use timer.cancel();
and for example start faster timer for finish progress..

```
imer timer= new Timer();
     timer.schedule(
                    new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(
                                    new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {

                                    **thise code run every 100ms**

                                }
                            }
                    );
                }
            }, 0, 100);
```

it's simply, if you want correctly resolve thise problem use Threats.

Comment: thanks you, but I just dont know how I can make my progress bar display as my picture show above :(. Your code just repeat an action per 100ms. I using ansytask to get data from server and display progress when download. I want my progress bar display as picture I showing above.

Comment: you have grafic for it? or it's only suggestion

Comment: grafic? what do you mean ?

Comment: pictures. png file ... what you want implement on the project.

Comment: pictures. I think I found solution for my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900747/custom-progress-dialog-with-squre-image-rotation-with-asyntask. This is exactly what I want :). Thanks you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?

You should look on Android Threading concepts. and as mentioned remember runOnUiThread for calls that updates your UI.

You should extend a progressbar and handle the images position on it...
Here is the AsyncTask example code:

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

}

Comment: Thanks you bro. I know how can make progress bar to display percent download file. But I want custom dialog progress bar as picture. And I found solution for my problem here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900747/custom-progress-dialog-with-squre-image-rotation-with-asyntask .